# AngularJs with Yeoman fails in Windows 7

Tags: angularjs, windows, yeoman-generator

I have install Yeoman, angular generator as Yeoman doc said but when I try to generate the application there is a message that said conflict and overwrites files, as result there are not any installation. 
Which is the correct way to install angular with Yeoman in Windows 7?

Comment: Have you installed as per this douucmention https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular .. the above information is not conveying what you tried etc .. plz update with some more information

Comment: Yes, I installed Yeoman with generator create a directory and inside call "yo angular myApp" the process begun and then messages saying it was necessary to rewrite. It was in Windows 7 with cmd as administrator.